# is it possible to create db using script in springboot app with flyway for postgres? if yes how?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, database-schema, flyway

Its my first time I am using flyway. My application is spring boot with flyway for db version controlling and postgres as db.
I have write successfully a script V1_1_0__create_schema1.sql for writing schema:

```
Create schema if not exists schema1;
```

and second script to create table V1_1_1__create_table.sql for writing table:

> ```
> create table if not exists schema1.table1( id int NOT NULL, name varchar(255), CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) );
> ```

Now i want to write sql script for database creation with flyway convention. how can i do it? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create db using script in springboot app with flyway
> for postgres?

Of course it is :D !

> If yes how?

First you will need to add flyway on your project, as a depenency (without a version if you are using spring dependency management or BOM) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then spring Boot will automatically detect and autowire Flyway with its DataSource and invoke it on startup.

By default flyway looks in `src/main/resources/db/migration` folder for migration scripts, those script must follow a naming convention as `V[version_number]__[Description_of_script].sql`, please note that you have 2 underscore, so as example you can have `V1__init_db.sql`

then you can configure datasource properties in your `application.properties` ,to activate flyway using :

```
spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
#if you have multiple schemas
spring.flyway.schemas=schema1,schema2
```

You can have a look at theses resources for more details there is a lot of options to explore there :

- [database-migrations-with-flyway](https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway).
- [build-a-spring-boot-app-with-flyway-and-postgres](https://dzone.com/articles/build-a-spring-boot-app-with-flyway-and-postgres).
- [spring_boot_flyway_database](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_flyway_database.htm)